# How to merge the bottom margin of an image and a container's padding

Tags: html, css, margin

I have two divs that each have a padding of 50px so they are 100px apart.  In the top div, I have an image that is right-floated with paragraphs around it.  My requirements team would like 20px of margin beneath the image if the text flows under the image and no margin if there is no text under the image.

```
<div class="panel">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45170/kittens-cat-cat-puppy-rush-45170.jpeg">
    <p>some text that may or may not flow under the image</p>
    <p>some text that may or may not flow under the image</p>
    <p>some text that may or may not flow under the image</p>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>text</p>
</div>

.panel {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

img {
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asgwL21v/12/

As you can see, when the text flows under the image, the space between the text and the line is 50px.  If the text doesn't flow under the image, the space between the image and the line is 70px.

Answer (score 0):

What if you reduce the bottom padding and allow margins to do the work?

```
.panel {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;   /* 20px will be supplied by margin */
  border-top:1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 20px;  /* Give the last paragraph 20px of margin just in case it flows past the image */
}

img {
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

In the code above, `20px` of additional whitespace will be added onto the parent container from either the image or the last paragraph of text, giving you `50px` total. [Here's an updated version of your Fiddle showing it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/asgwL21v/17/)